# Loading array file with other numbering format

Tags: numbers, format

I am trying to load a file in which the numbers are in the following form:

```
  0.0000000D+00 -0.1145210D-16  0.1262408D-16
  0.1000000D+00 -0.4697286D-06  0.1055963D-06
  0.2000000D+00 -0.1877806D-05  0.4220493D-06
  0.3000000D+00 -0.4220824D-05  0.9482985D-06
```

I am trying the numpy.loadtext function, but apparently it's not in its recognized numbering format as I'm getting the following error:

ValueError: could not convert string to float: b'0.0000000D+00'

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar, but is D designation for Decimal -- not Float?

Comment: which language you are using?

Comment: Python. This designation is the equivalent of

0.0000000E+00 -0.1145210E-16  0.1262408E-16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a converter with [numpy.loadtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) that converts the value to a parsable float. In this case we trivially replace `D`with `E`;

```py
import numpy as np

numconv = lambda x : str.replace(x.decode('utf-8'), 'D', 'E')
np.loadtxt('test.txt', converters={0:numconv, 1:numconv, 2:numconv}, dtype='double')

# array([[  0.00000000e+00,  -1.14521000e-17,   1.26240800e-17],
#        [  1.00000000e-01,  -4.69728600e-07,   1.05596300e-07],
#        [  2.00000000e-01,  -1.87780600e-06,   4.22049300e-07],
#        [  3.00000000e-01,  -4.22082400e-06,   9.48298500e-07]])
```